# How to make a Gigabit Ethernet crossover cable?

Tags: networking, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet, wired-networking, crossover-cable

Nowadays, I usually make [EIA/TIA-568A crossover cables for Fast Ethernet(10/100 Mbps) networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/568A). On these cables, just 2 of the 4 wire pairs are used to comunications(the 2 remaining could be used for [PoE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) or just for nothing), so I just needed to cross 2 color pairs(1-2 and 3-6 wires). However, on [Gigabit Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet) all the 4 wire pairs are used to increase the network bandwidth. So, to do a crossover on a Gigabit Ethernet I would need to cross all the 4 pairs. Is this feasible and reliable? I mean, how to make that and what is the correct color order of both ends of a Gigabit Ethernet crossover cable?

Comment: nowadays there is no need for such cables. You can use standard cable which supports 1Gbit (5E and upper)

Comment: Just to be sure, you are running 1000BASE-T ?  That's about 98% of hardware, but if you happen to be linking 1000BASE-TX the cross-over is the same as 100BASE-TX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wikipedia [has pinouts for a gigabit crossover cable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable#Crossover_cable_pinouts).

Note that while [Auto-MDIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-MDIX#Auto-MDIX) is an optional feature of the gigabit ethernet specification (IEEE 802.3-2008: "Implementation of an automatic MDI/MDI-X configuration is optional for 1000BASE-T devices"), most gigabit ethernet interfaces *do* implement it, so in most cases you will not need a special crossover cable.

Comment: same as 100BASE-T

Comment: it was my understanding that gigabit crossover is DIFFERENT from 100M and all 8 wires are a lot more twisted, and I remember that from a CISCO class I took years ago (and didn't used after ... always used a switch ... until now), also, I tested "normal" twisted (your webpage), even if network card report 1G connected, speed doesn't match up (I test transfer by moving data between ... ramdrives, on both computers just to be sure is not the speed of hard disk or something), and if I put a switch and non-crossover cables, then speed matches up

Comment: For those wondering (and @THESorcerer), there is more than what that wiki shows.  The crossover pinout for TIA/EIA-568b is: White/Green, Green, White/Orange, White/Brown, Brown, Orange, Blue, White/Blue.  Note that the blue & brown are swapped (blue replaces brown) and twisted (solid replaces white/color trace).

Answer (score 6):

You don't: Auto MDI-X is built into the Gigabit Ethernet spec.  The endpoints will auto-negotiate and take care of those communication issues.

Comment: So the endpoints will always take care of it by default?

Answer (score 6):

For gigabit this is the pin layout you want to follow

PIN 1 - PIN 3
PIN 2 - PIN 6
PIN 3 - PIN 1
PIN 6 - PIN 2

So far this is a regular crossover cable. for gigabit use

PIN 4 - PIN 7
PIN 5 - PIN 8
PIN 7 - PIN 4
PIN 8 - PIN 5

For a color graphic guide follow the link below, is basically

ORANGE/WHITE
ORANGE
GREEN/WHITE
BROWN/WHITE
BROWN
GREEN
BLUE
BLUE/WHITE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct. The solids always go to the solids, and the white stripe to the white stripe. The drawing is incorrect. The Tyco Products PDF instruction sheet is the correct way. See  https://cdn.tycosp.com/docs/illustra.products/flex-mini-dome/Knowledge%20Base/Ethernet-Crossover-Cable-Gigabit_en.pdf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: getting access denied. Can you please mirror or copy here the relevant information?

Answer (score -1):

Concerning a four pair crossover cable, for pairs on pins 1/2, 3/6, 7/8, the lower number pin is tip and the higher is ring (not to be confused with Transmit and Receive).  However, in the 5/4 pair, 5 is tip and 4 is ring.  This is indicated by the white stripe of each pair.  Can anyone explain how 5 tip can crossover to 8 ring?  The polarity of 7/8 would be reversed.

Comment: While this has some good content it is best as a comment NOT an answer