# Are crossover ethernet cables not working anymore on modern ethernet cards?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I made a crossover cable to connect two computers. The connections are correct, and I verified the cable both visually and with a tester. However, no matter what I tried, I could not make it to work. I then plugged a normal (non-twisted) cable, for which autosensing probably kicked in and solved the issue, and they communicate perfectly.

So now I am left open with a question. How is it possible that a crossover cable does not work?
Is there some ethernet change I wasn't made aware of in the past 10 years that made crossover cables not working anymore?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Gigabit Ethernet crossover cable?](http://superuser.com/questions/410437/how-to-make-a-gigabit-ethernet-crossover-cable)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 : I perfectly know how to make a cable. I don't know why it's not working while all tests seems to say it should.

Comment: With modern NICs, both straight-through and crossover should work and the configuration should be more or less the same. Maybe if you added details about OS/configuration, etc we may be able to spot something amiss?

Comment: The suggested duplicate might be useful to verify whether the cable was modified correctly, but that it not what was asked in the question.  It isn't a duplicate question.

Comment: @MaQleod: They are two linux ubuntu machines. You confirm that crossovers should still work, which pretty much answers my question. The cable is correct, confirmed with both visual examination and with an electric tester. So, the only possibility is that the cable is internally broken and when I move it around it drops the electric connection.